# Filter on dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to filter on dict. For example

```
col_dict_req
Out[165]: 
{'id': {'datatype': 'int'},
 'Com': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'Nam': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'place': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'age': {'datatype': 'float'},
 'status': {'datatype': 'bool'}}
```

Expected output (Removed place and age)

```
col_dict_req
Out[165]: 
{'id': {'datatype': 'int'},
 'Com': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'Nam': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'status': {'datatype': 'bool'}}
```

Comment: What exactly is the condition you want to filter on?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Did you try *anything* at all?

Comment: Its a dynamice one. There is another varible that contains strings for example in this case, it is ````'place' and 'age'````. This could more than 2 also. We just have to exclde this strings from main dict

Comment: @vitp why don't you ad that to your question?

Comment: sorry. My bad....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
col_dict_req = {'id': {'datatype': 'int'},
 'Com': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'Nam': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'place': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'age': {'datatype': 'float'},
 'status': {'datatype': 'bool'}}

want_check = ['id','Com','Nam','status']
print({k:v for k,v in col_dict_req.items() if k in want_check})
```

Output:

```
{'Com': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'Nam': {'datatype': 'char'},
 'id': {'datatype': 'int'},
 'status': {'datatype': 'bool'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would checking for keys inside of an try: except: statement work for you? You could then try to simply remove desired values if they are present in the dictionary.

Comment: hi, this looks more like a comment than an answer. If that *is* the case, and my understanding resonates with your intent, could you please post this above in the comments section? Else, you can try to elaborate what you're trying to say with an example code and its understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
Out[165].pop('place')
Out[165].pop('age')
```

You can use a list to store the key value to be filtered，then use a loop to filter all the key values